# Relation between stationary distribution and derivatives of autocorrelation for Gaussian process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $x(t)$ be a stationary Gaussian process with derivative $v(t)$. Let the stationary distribution be $p(x,v) = e^{-A x^2 - B v^2}$. Let the normalized autocorrelation function of $x(t)$ be $\rho(t)$. Then

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |v| p(0,v)\, dv = \frac{1}{\pi} \sqrt{- \rho''(0)}.$$

> For context, this is a step in the proof of [Rice's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_formula). I'd appreciate help deriving it.
>
> From the definition $\rho(t) = \langle x(t') x(t'+t)\rangle$ (up to normalization) we find $\rho''(0) = \langle x(t') x''(t')\rangle$. But I have no way of computing this or relating it to the left-hand side. If I square the left-hand side I get something that looks like $\langle x'(t') x'(t')\rangle$, but I don't see the relation with the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the dot-shifting formula, or in your case dash-shifting. For any stationary time correlation function we can differentiate with respect to $t'$, the time *origin*, and the result must be zero:
$$
\frac{d}{d t'} \langle A(t') B(t'+t) \rangle
=  \langle A'(t') B(t'+t) \rangle +  \langle A(t') B'(t'+t) \rangle = 0
$$
So, setting $t=0$ we get
$$
\langle A'(t')B(t')\rangle = -\langle A(t')B'(t')\rangle
$$
For your case, let $A=x'$ and $B=x$.
$$
\langle x''(t')x(t')\rangle = -\langle x'(t')x'(t')\rangle
$$
This should be the missing link between the left hand side and the right hand side.

Comment: Incredible. Thanks.